# Compiling in emacs

Tags: emacs

When I try to compile a  Hello World program in emacs, using

`g++ -Wall Hello.cpp`

I receive the following error:

`/bin/bash: g++: command not found
  Compilation exited abnormally with code 127`

I get the same error with the c++ command substituted for g++, as well as when I create a makefile

`hello: Hello.cpp
         g++ -Wall -g Hello.cpp -o hello`

I am new to linux and emacs. Using GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (i386-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.20.1) on Fedora 13 OS.

I just want to write and execute simple C++ programs to teach myself, since I take it this computer fad is not going away.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have not installed g++. Run the following command to install g++ on Fedora:

```
yum install gcc-c++
```